# Shareable Vite/Vue component - why am I getting error about missing CSS export?

Tags: vue.js, npm, components, vite

I've been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QV9wVc8c7g) to build a shareable Vue component via Vite, which I'm then testing by `npm link`ing it into another project.

After building with Vite via `npm run bulid` and then linking, I end up with this structure in my other project's `node_modules` dir:

```
- mycomponent
    - dist
        - style.css
        - mycomponent.es.js
        - mycomponent.umd
```

I can successfully import my component - BUT it lacks CSS! So according to the above video I needed to do (in my `main.js`):

```
import MyComponent from 'mycomponent'
import 'mycomponent/dist/style.css'
...
const app = createApp(App)
    .use(...)
    .use(Mycomponent)
```

I don't really want it to be globally available in this way, but I'm just trying to fix the CSS issue. Anyway, this results in the following error:

> **[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Missing "./style.css" export in "mycomponent" package**

What am I doing wrong? Given my component was built as a SFC, why do I even need to import its CSS separately? And the file `/dist/style.css` does exist.

Here's my component's `package.json` > `exports`, incidentally:

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/mycomponent.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/mycomponent.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Exports is a key/map which should be mirrored in the imports.

In my case I had `"./style.css": "./dist/style.css"`
and so got this error trying to `import 'my-lib/dist/style.css'` which was resolved when matching the import to the key from exports: `import 'my-lib/style.css'`

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll give it a go.